# Adding an Appbar in xaml (Universal App)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How do I add an appbar with buttons to a Windows Phone 8.1 app using the Hub template?
I do not see any clear examples of how to do this.

Specifically, using the Hub template, I want to add appbar menu items to the ItemsPage.xaml.

Comment: I've removed a tag from question's title - please note than in most cases questions [shouldn't include tag in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). I've also added an appropriate one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 projects you have to use the **CommandBar** API.

Take a look [**on this guide**,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh781230.aspx) it's for Windows 8.1, but the syntax is exactly same. Note that you have to only use the **BottomAppBar** where the **PrimaryCommands** are displayed as standard AppBar buttons as we know them, and the **SecondaryCommands** are displayed as Menu Items.

Comment: <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Send" Label="Sort" Click="Send_Clicked">
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>